# Is the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)$ exist$\}$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f$ be a Lebesgue Measurable Function on $\mathbb{R}$. 
>   Is the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)$ exist$\}$ always measurable?

I can prove if $a\in \mathbb{R}$ is given $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \lim_{y\rightarrow x}f(y)=a\}$ is measurable by showing the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit only requires $\frac{1}{n}$ values($n\in \mathbb{N}$) for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ and write the set as countable union/intersection of measurable sets. However I don't think we can do the same thing for $a$ becuase it has uncountably many possibilities.

Comment: considering I remember it taking my professor an entire lecture to construct a non-measurable set, and he had to use the Axiom of Choice to do it, this set is almost certainly measurable.

Comment: @Thoth: I wouldn't be so convinced, there are plenty of easily constructed non-measurable sets, e.g. a set of representatives of the quotient of [0,1) by the relation x~y <=> x-y is rational.

Comment: Often you can circumvent the "uncountably many $a$" issue by considering the Cauchy criterion for convergence.  I don't quite see how to do it here, but then again I don't see how to do the "given $a$" case either.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, I edit the question to include my answer for "given a" case.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.  You're looking for the set of all $x$ satisfying some property, so it doesn't make sense to have $x$ appearing as a free variable in the definition of the set.

Comment: nice question +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will consider a variant of the oscillation; first, for $x\in\mathbb R$ and $\delta>0$, define $I(x,\delta)=(x-\delta,x)\cup(x,x+\delta)$, and let $$\omega_{\delta}(x)=\sup_{I(x,\delta)}f-\inf_{I(x,\delta)}f.$$ Define also $$\omega(x)=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\omega_{1/n}(x).$$ Suppose that $\lim_{y\to x}f(y)=a\in\mathbb R$ for some $x$, and let $\varepsilon>0$. Then, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that, if $y\in I(x,1/m)$, for $m\geq N$, then $|f(y)-a|<\varepsilon$. This shows that $\omega_{1/m}(x)\leq 2\varepsilon$ for all $m\geq N$, therefore $\omega(x)=0$.

Conversely, if $\omega(x)=0$, we can show that $f$ has a limit at $x$. Therefore, the set of points at which $f$ has a limit is equal to the set of roots of $f$.

It will be enough now to show that $\omega$ is measurable. From its definition, it is enough to show that $\omega_{1/n}$ is measurable for $n\in\mathbb N$, therefore it is enough to show that $$\sup_{I(x,1/n)}f,\,\,\inf_{I(x,1/n)}f$$ are measurable, as functions of $x$, which is true. Therefore, the set of points for which the limit of $f$ exists is measureable.

Comment: How does one see that $x \mapsto \sup_{I(x,1/n)} f$ is measurable?  That is the hard part for me.  The inf, of course, would be similar.

Comment: Same question as Nate. I have an answer typed since 2 hours ago, but I couldn't easily show that that sup is measurable.

Comment: Ok, it seems that this is not straightforward; I'll try to come up with a proof for this.